# Access Twitter API with JQuery only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter

I'm want to retrieve data from Twitter. I got it to work with [j7mbo](https://github.com/j7mbo/twitter-api-php),  a PHP Wrapper for the Twitter API.

So I set up a PHP service. I access it with Ajax, the service itself access  then Twitter's API. The response is send back and parsed, all with JQuery.

But is there also a plain JQuery approach, without using PHP?

PS: I'm interested in Twitter's trends.

Comment: try this: http://jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/#sthash.4vsNbM7M.dpbs

Comment: @swatkins: I'm interested in the trends, rather than the tweets.

Comment: The trends api requires authentication. Probably not a good idea to authenticate client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, twitter doesn't allow external sites to make CORS requests to https://api.twitter.com.  So this is not possible without writing a full twitter client including oauth authentication in javascript.